Getting error for using Raydium SDK: Transaction instruction index 0 has undefined program id
I'm trying to do a simple swap on raydium but i keep getting an error of undefined program ID
here is my code:
const poolInfo = {
    "id": "H36eDWAtAZ2JytqrMur2TCn4aQJvqKD3F8ZhZGeepqUD",
    "baseMint" : "83mCq15ngmFmjhfTaRf3oNqu5AfNQAw5uH1eCjsTcZxh",
    "quoteMint" : "So11111111111111111111111111111111111111112"
};

async function finalBuy() {
    const raydiumSwap = new RaydiumSwap(
        RPC,
        thePK
    );
    
    const amountIn = 0.0001;
    const toToken = "83mCq15ngmFmjhfTaRf3oNqu5AfNQAw5uH1eCjsTcZxh"; 
    // or: const toToken = "So11111111111111111111111111111111111111112"; 

    try {
        const swapTransaction = await raydiumSwap.getSwapTransaction(
            toToken,
            amountIn,
            poolInfo
        );
    
        console.log('Swap transaction instructions:', swapTransaction.instructions);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error getting swap transaction:', error);
    }

    return
}

and the RaydiumSwap class:
class RaydiumSwap {
    constructor(RPC_URL, WALLET_PRIVATE_KEY) {
        this.connection = new Connection(RPC_URL, {
            commitment: "confirmed"
        })
        this.wallet = new Wallet(
            Keypair.fromSecretKey(Uint8Array.from(bs58.decode(WALLET_PRIVATE_KEY)))
        )
    }

    async getSwapTransaction(toToken, amount, poolInfo, maxLamports = 100000, useVersionedTransaction = true, fixedSide = "in") {
        const directionIn = poolInfo.quoteMint.toString() == toToken

        const {
            minAmountOut,
            amountIn
        } = await this.calcAmountOut(poolInfo, amount, directionIn)

        const userTokenAccounts = await this.getOwnerTokenAccounts()
        const swapTransaction = await Liquidity.makeSwapInstructionSimple({
            connection: this.connection,
            makeTxVersion: useVersionedTransaction ? 0 : 1,
            poolKeys: {
                id: poolInfo.id,
                baseMint: poolInfo.baseMint,
                quoteMint: poolInfo.quoteMint
            },
            userKeys: {
                tokenAccounts: userTokenAccounts,
                owner: this.wallet.publicKey
            },
            amountIn: amountIn,
            amountOut: minAmountOut,
            fixedSide: fixedSide,
            config: {
                bypassAssociatedCheck: false
            },
            computeBudgetConfig: {
                microLamports: maxLamports
            }
        })

        const recentBlockhashForSwap = await this.connection.getLatestBlockhash()
        const instructions = swapTransaction.innerTransactions[0].instructions.filter(
            Boolean
        )

        if (useVersionedTransaction) {
            const versionedTransaction = new VersionedTransaction(
                new TransactionMessage({
                    payerKey: this.wallet.publicKey,
                    recentBlockhash: recentBlockhashForSwap.blockhash,
                    instructions: instructions
                }).compileToV0Message()
            )

            versionedTransaction.sign([this.wallet.payer])

            return versionedTransaction
        }

        const legacyTransaction = new Transaction({
            blockhash: recentBlockhashForSwap.blockhash,
            lastValidBlockHeight: recentBlockhashForSwap.lastValidBlockHeight,
            feePayer: this.wallet.publicKey
        })

        legacyTransaction.add(...instructions)

        return legacyTransaction
    }

    async getOwnerTokenAccounts() {
        const walletTokenAccount = await this.connection.getTokenAccountsByOwner(
            this.wallet.publicKey, {
                programId: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID
            }
        )

        return walletTokenAccount.value.map(i => ({
            pubkey: i.pubkey,
            programId: i.account.owner,
            accountInfo: SPL_ACCOUNT_LAYOUT.decode(i.account.data)
        }))
    }

    async calcAmountOut(poolInfo, rawAmountIn, swapInDirection) {
        const poolKeys = {
            id: poolInfo.id,
            baseMint: poolInfo.baseMint,
            quoteMint: poolInfo.quoteMint
        };

        const poolInfoRetrieved = await Liquidity.fetchInfo({
            connection: this.connection,
            poolKeys
        })

        let currencyInMint = poolKeys.baseMint
        let currencyInDecimals = poolInfoRetrieved.baseDecimals
        let currencyOutMint = poolKeys.quoteMint
        let currencyOutDecimals = poolInfoRetrieved.quoteDecimals

        if (!swapInDirection) {
            currencyInMint = poolKeys.quoteMint
            currencyInDecimals = poolInfoRetrieved.quoteDecimals
            currencyOutMint = poolKeys.baseMint
            currencyOutDecimals = poolInfoRetrieved.baseDecimals
        }

        const currencyIn = new Token(
            TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
            currencyInMint,
            currencyInDecimals
        )
        const amountIn = new TokenAmount(currencyIn, rawAmountIn, false)
        const currencyOut = new Token(
            TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
            currencyOutMint,
            currencyOutDecimals
        )
        const slippage = new Percent(5, 100) // 5% slippage

        const {
            amountOut,
            minAmountOut,
            currentPrice,
            executionPrice,
            priceImpact,
            fee
        } = Liquidity.computeAmountOut({
            poolKeys,
            poolInfo: poolInfoRetrieved,
            amountIn,
            currencyOut,
            slippage
        })

        return {
            amountIn,
            amountOut,
            minAmountOut,
            currentPrice,
            executionPrice,
            priceImpact,
            fee
        }
    }
}

The poolInfo data areare correct as they are fetched from https://api.raydium.io/v2/sdk/liquidity/mainnet.json (triple checked)
However i keep getting this error:
Error getting swap transaction: Error: Transaction instruction index 0 has undefined program id
I'd really appreciate any help. thanks
